# Android SurfaceView - timeRecords is at its maximum size[64]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, surfaceview, surfaceflinger

I am developing a 2D game for mobile using Unity.
I am getting the following error on devices running Android 12 only. The project has target API 31. Previous Android versions are not getting this error.

`2022-09-02 12:33:40.847 647-647/? E/TimeStats: [1572]-[SurfaceView[com.abc.ProjectName/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity](BLAST)#0]-timeRecords is at its maximum size[64]. Ignore this when unittesting.`

These lines are flooding the logcat. The game is running but the errors keep coming.
I found where the error is coming from: [Here](https://gerrit.pixelexperience.org/plugins/gitiles/frameworks_native/+/1d4249acec3ee6a936f2400177a3316b60388057/services/surfaceflinger/TimeStats/TimeStats.cpp#266)

I don't understand what is causing this error neither have I any idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.